# Google sheets Keep formatting when coping from one sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been searching for days on how to do this. I have tried 12 different scripts so far. I can copy over but not the formatting, it is killing me. I have two sheets. [Sheet A](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16QcYsC3mbdcYiPsCp7tPFPX-pCePkaITzfF-bK4ceu0/edit?usp=sharing) and [Sheet B](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16OBwPrYmKnZZkgovDDUYByJhssU2nbRkBD0hCrgvYK4/edit?usp=sharing).

I want to copy over columns A through I  onto sheet B And keep the formatting. I have 2 problems the first is It copies everything instead of just the columns I want. The second is it does not keep the formatting. I have tried different scripts just for formatting and different lines of code. but so far none have worked for me.

Current Script:

```
function CopyDataToNewFile() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('16QcYsC3mbdcYiPsCp7tPFPX-pCePkaITzfF-bK4ceu0'); // sss = source spreadsheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // ss = source sheet
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  var SData = SRange.getValues();
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('16OBwPrYmKnZZkgovDDUYByJhssU2nbRkBD0hCrgvYK4'); // tss = target spreadsheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // ts = target sheet
  ts.clear({contentsOnly: true});
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);
}
```

Comment: Keep which formatting? the format of the values from sheet A? Or the format in the cells whose values are altered, on sheet B?

Comment: Relevant documentation: [`getDataRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange()), [`getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)), [`copyFormatToRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyFormatToRange(Sheet,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)), [`copyTo()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range))

Comment: I need to keep the same formatting of sheet A. I need an exact copy just from column A thru Column I. So On sheet A some things are in Red and some in Green. I need to see that on Sheet B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understood what you want to do as follows.

1. You want to copy the values of from column A to column I.
2. You want to also copy the values with the format of source range.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them. In this modification, `copyTo()` of Class Range and `copyTo()` of Class Sheet are used for this situation. The flow of this is as follows.

#### Flow :

1. Retrieve the source range.
2. Retrieve the destination range.
3. Copy the sheet of source range to a temporal sheet. copyTo() of Class Range is used.
4. Copy the source range to the destination range. copyTo() of Class Range is used.
5. Delete the temporal sheet.

#### Modified script :

```
function CopyDataToNewFile() {
  var range = "A:K"; // Range you want to copy

  // Source
  var srcss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("16QcYsC3mbdcYiPsCp7tPFPX-pCePkaITzfF-bK4ceu0");
  var srcsheet = srcss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var srsrange = srcsheet.getRange(range);

  // Destination
  var dstss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("16OBwPrYmKnZZkgovDDUYByJhssU2nbRkBD0hCrgvYK4");
  var dstrange = dstss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(range);

  // Copy values
  var copiedsheet = srcsheet.copyTo(dstss);
  copiedsheet.getRange(range).copyTo(dstrange);
  dstss.deleteSheet(copiedsheet);
}
```

#### References :

- [copyTo()  of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet))
- [copyTo() of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range))

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Works FANTASTIC to Copy the format and the page! One little thing. How do I set the rang to copy just certain columns? I need to copy A thru K. I see the rang section. How do I add it in?

Comment: @Connie I'm sorry for my incomplete answer. I cannot understand about "I need to copy A thru K.". You want to copy the column A of source sheet to column K of destination sheet? I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: No I am sorry, I did not explain myself well. I need to copy Columns A thru K of source sheet. To Sheet B. And I do not know how to set to copy only those columns not the entire sheet.

Comment: @Connie I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Please confirm it. If this didn't work, please tell me. I would like to modify.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have been working on this alone for days. I feel so old..lol I really appreciate your help. It works great!

Comment: I was so close I tried the var rang = but I used ( ) instead of " " ... so close.lol

Comment: @Connie Thank you for your response. If you have any questions for this, feel free to tell me.

Comment: I'm sure others will want to know. I saw this asked in a lot of places but yours is the only answer that worked for me.

Comment: @Connie Thank you.