# Set values to ranges in a different spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, setvalue

Can anybody offer suggestions about how to update or set values to a range in a different spreadsheet.  I know the importRange function will bring values into the active sheet, but I want to "push" a single row of data from the active sheet to a row at the bottom of a sheet called FinalData, which is in a different spreadsheet.

The data I want to "push" is populated by other code, resulting in a single row of data in a sheet called TempData.  The data exists in range TempData!A2:U2.

My goal is to append data from TempData!A2:U2 to a new row at the bottom of a table called "DataFinal", which is in a completely separate google spreadsheet (but on the same "google drive".)

Here's what I tried so far:

```
// Row to FinalData
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();

   var startSheet = ss.getSheetByName("TempData");

   var sourceRange = ss.getRange ("TempData!A2:U");

   var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1bWKS_Z1JwLSCO5WSq1iNP1LLQpVXnspA4WkzdyxYDNY");

   var targetSheet = target.getSheetByName("DataFinal");

   var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();

   targetSheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow); 

   sourceRange.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1), {contentsOnly: true});
```

When I run it I get an error that says "Target range and source range must be on the same spreadsheet.".  There must be a way to do this-- any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`copyTo()` can be used for the same spreadsheet.

From your script, I think that you can achieve it using `getValues()` and `setValues()`, because you use `contentsOnly: true`. So how about this modification?

#### From :

```
sourceRange.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1), {contentsOnly: true})
```

#### To :

```
var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, sourceValues.length, sourceValues[0].length).setValues(sourceValues);
```

#### Note :

- If you want to use `copyTo()`, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137336/google-sheets-keep-formatting-when-coping-from-one-sheet-to-another/49141148#49141148) might be useful for your situation.

#### References :

- [copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-copypastetype-transposed)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

If this was not what you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Oh my gosh it worked!   Thank you so much!!! I have spent hours slogging thru the intenet trying to figure out how to do this.  You made it look easy!  I SO MUCH appreciate it!   Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: @Carolyn I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too!