# specific onEdit functions from library don't work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a library ('CustomerReportLibrary') that has a few functions for which I created installable onEdit triggers from the spreadsheet script.
Two specific functions from this library don't work (the others do..). Can anybody shed light about the reason for that?

The functions that don't work:

```
function restoreRangeSettings(e) {
// retrieves data validation, conditional formatting and formatting settings from template
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var A1Notation = range.getA1Notation();
  var templateRange = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheet.getName() + ' design').getRange(A1Notation);

  templateRange.copyTo(range, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
  templateRange.copyTo(range, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING, false);
  templateRange.copyTo(range, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION, false);
}

function logTimestamp(e) {
// logs task last edit timestamp
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var editedRow = editedCell.getRow();
  var editedColumn = editedCell.getColumn();
  var emailCell = sheet.getRange(editedRow,5);
  var dateCell = sheet.getRange(editedRow,4);
  var time = new Date();
  time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+02", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

  // don't do anything if edited sheets are not task sheets
  if ((sheet.getName() == 'instructions') || (sheet.getName() == 'generate report')) {return;}

  // logs timestamp when the edited range is within the task documentation table
  if ((editedColumn() > 7) && (editedRow > 4)) {
    // adds user and month to also to next row when task is added
    if ((sheet.getRange(editedRow,5,1,3).getValues() != '') && (editedColumn == 8) && (sheet.getRange(editedRow+1,4).isBlank())) {
      sheet.getRange(editedRow+1,5,1,3).setValues(sheet.getRange(editedRow,5,1,3).getValues());
    }
    dateCell.setValue(time);
  }
}
```

The code in the spreadsheet script:

```
function EditTriggers() {
  var customerSsId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  var customerSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(customerSsId);

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('CustomerReportLibrary.restoreRangeSettings')
  .forSpreadsheet(customerSpreadsheet)
  .onEdit()
  .create();

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('CustomerReportLibrary.logTimestamp')
  .forSpreadsheet(customerSpreadsheet)
  .onEdit()
  .create();

  //works fine
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('CustomerReportLibrary.showRowsAndComments')
  .forSpreadsheet(customerSpreadsheet)
  .onEdit()
  .create();

  //works fine
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('CustomerReportLibrary.optShortcuts')
  .forSpreadsheet(customerSpreadsheet)
  .onEdit()
  .create();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly does not work? The functions themselves or calling them `onEdit`?

Comment: If you found an [answer from a previous question helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59476907/11551468), please make sure to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) before copying the code from it and using it to ask another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am happy to update that the issue is resolved!

## First action (logTimestamp)

```
  if ((editedColumn() > 7) && (editedRow > 4)) {
```

I accidently referred to *editedColumn* as a function and not a variable.

## Second action (restoreRangeSettings)

I have chosen a different strategy for the required result, base on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137336/google-sheets-keep-formatting-when-coping-from-one-sheet-to-another). (See discussion about what I tried to achieve [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59475857/google-spreadsheet-treat-ctrl-v-as-ctrl-shift-v/59614300#59614300).)

## Third action (general)

I palyed a bit with variables defenition. For example - defining the range as "`e.range`" did not work, while defining it as "`e.source.getActiveRange()`" magically did.

## Finally - the final code

```
function restoreRangeSettings(e) {
// retrieves data validation, conditional formatting and formatting settings from template
  var editedSs = e.source;
  var editedRange = editedSs.getActiveRange();
  var editedSh = editedRange.getSheet().getName();

  var templateSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('10zVclYTCEOEwskUID4vxSPxKR_tb3RaR76eG7TfxLUE');
  var templateSh = templateSs.getSheetByName(editedSh);
  var copiedSh = templateSh.copyTo(editedSs).hideSheet();
  var templateRange = editedSs.getSheetByName(copiedSh.getName()).getRange(editedRange.getA1Notation());

  templateRange.copyTo(editedRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
  templateRange.copyTo(editedRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING, false);
  templateRange.copyTo(editedRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION, false);

  editedSs.deleteSheet(copiedSh);
}

function logTimestamp(e) {
// logs task last edit timestamp
  var editedRange = e.range;
  var editedSh = editedRange.getSheet();
  var editedRow = editedRange.getRow();
  var editedColumn = editedRange.getColumn();
  var emailCell = editedSh.getRange(editedRow,5);
  var dateCell = editedSh.getRange(editedRow,4);
  var time = new Date();
  time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+02", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

  // don't do anything if edited sheets are not task sheets
  if ((editedSh.getName() == 'instructions') || (editedSh.getName() == 'generate report')) {return;}

  // logs timestamp when the edited range is within the task documentation table
  if ((editedColumn > 7) && (editedRow > 4)) {
    // adds user and month to also to next row when task is added
    if ((editedSh.getRange(editedRow,5,1,3).getValues() != '') && (editedColumn == 8) && (editedSh.getRange(editedRow+1,4).isBlank())) {
      editedSh.getRange(editedRow+1,5,1,3).setValues(editedSh.getRange(editedRow,5,1,3).getValues());
    }
    dateCell.setValue(time);
  }
}
```

**Note**: spreadsheet script did not change.